# Oracle how to export query to a text/csv file

Tags: oracle, plsql, csv, export, text-files

I was wondering how to go about exporting a query from PL/SQL to an text file or csv file. The query I have in mind exports a huge amount of data (about 1 gig). So I'd also like the data split across multiple files;

out1.csv
out2.csv
out3.csv

I'd like to be able to decide how many files to split it across.

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [UTL_FILE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm).

A well known ( probably the most complete discussion on this topic ) discussion on this can be found at Ask Tom, [Here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:88212348059) , note that many of the examples there date back to oracle 8, so there may be better ways to do it in your version of Oracle.

Comment: I'm that familiar with Oracle and PL/SQL could you please give a litte more detail?

Comment: Yep, I was looking for more info, but couldn't find it.. then realised that its UTL_FILE, not DBMS_FILE. I've linked the package spec. Its just a package for reading/writing files to disk

Comment: Cool thanks, however I still need to work out how to direct the output to the file and how to perform the spanning.

Comment: For the cursor-to-csv part, have a look at [www.williamrobertson.net/documents/refcursor-to-csv.shtml](http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/refcursor-to-csv.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

For creating MYDIR

```
create or replace directory MYDIR as 'F:/DATA/';
```

Grant all permission to **MYDIR** via **SYS** user
execute this procedure

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE export_to_csv(refcur out sys_refcursor) IS
      v_file   UTL_FILE.file_type;
      v_string VARCHAR2(4000);
      CURSOR c_emp IS
        SELECT ROLE_ID, ROLE_DESC FROM role_mst;
    BEGIN
      open refcur for
        SELECT ROLE_ID, ROLE_DESC FROM role_mst;
      v_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('MYDIR', 'empdata.csv', 'w', 1000);       
      -- if you do not want heading then remove below two lines
      v_string := 'Emp Code, Emp Name';
      UTL_FILE.put_line(v_file, v_string);
      FOR cur IN c_emp LOOP
        v_string := cur.ROLE_ID || ',' || cur.ROLE_DESC;
        UTL_FILE.put_line(v_file, v_string);
      END LOOP;
      UTL_FILE.fclose(v_file);
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
        IF UTL_FILE.is_open(v_file) THEN
          UTL_FILE.fclose(v_file);
        END IF;
    END;
```

Comment: How does this take into account commas within the field?