# How to import Oracle export into MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, mysql-workbench

I got .dmp export file from Oracle database. Now I want to import this file into MySQL workbench.

I tried using Data 'Import/Restore' link in MANAGEMENT menu. When I imported my .dmp file it says its finished import. But in schema its not showing that database.

I tried to look at this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667705/how-to-import-a-dmp-file-oracle-into-mysql-db), but its not giving me any proper solution. Is there any other way to import?

Answer (score 1):

oracle dmp files are proprietary and cannot be imported into non-oracle databases

Comment: MySQL is owned by Oracle, it's not an unreasonable ask.