# Help installing cx_Oracle

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I'm trying to install the cx_Oracle for Python 2.6, but it is failing.  I don't know enough about C or MS Vis. Studio's compiler to even approach fixing it myself.

This is what is output on the command line:

```
C:\pydev\cx_Oracle-5.0.1>C:\python26\python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'cx_Oracle' extension
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Oracle\instantclient\sdk\include -IC:\p
ython26\include -IC:\python26\PC /Tccx_Oracle.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.6-11g\Release\cx_Oracle.obj -DBUILD_VERSION=5.0.1
cx_Oracle.c
c:\pydev\cx_oracle-5.0.1\StringVar.c(392) : warning C4018: '>' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\pydev\cx_oracle-5.0.1\StringVar.c(417) : warning C4018: '>' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\pydev\cx_oracle-5.0.1\ObjectVar.c(117) : warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\pydev\cx_oracle-5.0.1\ObjectVar.c(134) : warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\pydev\cx_oracle-5.0.1\Variable.c(331) : error C2036: 'void *' : unknown size
c:\pydev\cx_oracle-5.0.1\Variable.c(878) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'sb2' to 'sb1', possible loss of data
c:\pydev\cx_oracle-5.0.1\Variable.c(914) : warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
error: command '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?
(I also may have an issue with that cl.exe file, I think I remember seeing this as a problem somewhere else, but I have four Windows machines which could have had issue there.).

*----------------------------- EDIT -----------------------------*

The reason I do not use the pre-compiled installer is because when I try to run the module I get the following:

```
    Python 2.6.3 (r263rc1:75186, Oct  2 2009, 20:40:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import cx_Oracle
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I assume that means that it has not been properly installed.  If someone can tell me what I did wrong here, that would also be a perfectly acceptable answer.

*----------------------------- EDIT2 -----------------------------*

I have retrieved *all* files from [Oracle's Basic Client](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/oci/instantclient/htdocs/winsoft.html) version 11.1.0.7.  I have not tried installing a more substantial client.  I am downloading one now.

```
%ORACLE_HOME%=C:\Oracle\instantclient\ #The directory where the above files have been extracted.
```

### More information

- The current directory for the cx_Oracle's setup.py is C:\pydev\cx_Oracle-5.0.1
- The version of Python is 2.6.3
- The current directory for Python is C:\Python26 -- to access python 2.6 -> type py26 on the command line and it will map to C:\python26\python

Comment: The errors in the compiler are only warnings and should not have stopped the build - are there other errors (still use the prebuilt one as I suspect you will have the same issues in the end)

Comment: For the prebuilt one - what is your path and where are your cx_oracle and oracle DLLS installed

Comment: i had to add the instantclient directory to the PATH variable after installing the prebuilt cx_oracle for the python script to work

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why don't you use a binary package like [Windows Installer (Oracle 10g, Python 2.6)](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/cx-oracle/cx_Oracle-5.0.2-10g.win32-py2.6.msi?download)?

See http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/ for other binary packages

---

Addendum (as requested): you must ensure to use the cx_Oracle that :

- set ORACLE_HOME if this environment variable doesn't exist (see this [Oracle FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORACLE_HOME))
- python can find `oraocci11.dll` for Oracle 11g, `oraocci10.dll` for Oracle 10g or `oraclient9.dll` for Oracle 9i by adding the folder (should be %ORACLE_HOME%/bin) where the DLL is in you PATH environment variable
- use the correct binary package (i.e. built for the right Python/Oracle versions)

Comment: +1 because it is a correct answer (and could have easily been overlooked -- I even forgot to write that I've tried it), but unfortunately it does not actually solve my problem...  This is one of those cases where I really wish I had been stupid enough to overlook the obvious...

Comment: The problem is loading oracle dll I assume. Check if c:\Oracle is in you PATH environment variable

Comment: *TECHNICALLY* this answer is incomplete.  Could you put the suggestion to include ORACLE_HOME in my PATH variable?

Comment: I could be wrong about this, but I don't believe that setting the ORACLE_HOME environment variable is the preferred way to do this on windows.  Instead, you should probably use the Home selector:  http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/em.112/e12255/oui2_manage_oracle_homes.htm#i1006001

Comment: @Jason, the important thing is the path modification, I think ORACLE_HOME is set by the Oracle installer and is not required by python. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 8):

You also need some type of Oracle client installed on your machine, since cx_Oracle is just a bridge between Python and the Oracle Client.  Valid Oracle Clients include a full Oracle installation (like Standard or XE) or the [Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/oci/instantclient/index.html)

From the [README](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/README.txt):

> Please note that an Oracle client (or
>   server) installation is required in
>   order to use cx_Oracle. If you do not
>   require the tools that come with a
>   full client installation, it is
>   recommended to install the Instant
>   Client which is far easier to install.

I have not installed on Windows before, but you may have to set the ORACLE_HOME environment variable so that cx_Oracle knows where to look.

Comment: I'm trying to install the more substantial version, but I already have basic "installed" (there is no .msi or .exe).

Comment: if you haven't installed on Windows, have you installed on Ubuntu/Debian?  I want to do that next.

Comment: I looked at this guide and made some minor tweaks (I am not using XE, but Standard with Instant Client): http://catherinedevlin.blogspot.com/2008/06/cxoracle-and-oracle-xe-on-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 3):

If you use Anaconda Python x64, things are [easier](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/cx_oracle):

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda cx_oracle
```

(It will install the right Oracle client)

---

If you get the following error:

```
[Anaconda2] C:\Users\User>conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda c
x_oracle
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: ......
Solving package specifications: .................
Package plan for installation in environment C:\Anaconda2:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    cx_oracle:            5.1.2-py27_0
    oracle-instantclient: 11.2.0.4.0-0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    conda:                3.19.1-py27_0 --> 4.0.5-py27_0
    pip:                  8.0.2-py27_0  --> 8.1.1-py27_0
    pyyaml:               3.11-py27_2   --> 3.11-py27_3
    setuptools:           19.6.2-py27_0 --> 20.3-py27_0
    wheel:                0.26.0-py27_1 --> 0.29.0-py27_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Unlinking packages ...
An unexpected error has occurred, please consider sending the            |   0%
following traceback to the conda GitHub issue tracker at:

    https://github.com/conda/conda/issues

Include the output of the command 'conda info' in your report.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda2\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 4, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 173, in main
    args_func(args, p)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 180, in args_fun
c
    args.func(args, p)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", line 45, in e
xecute
    install.install(args, parser, 'install')
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 423, in insta
ll
    plan.execute_actions(actions, index, verbose=not args.quiet)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\plan.py", line 538, in execute_acti
ons
    inst.execute_instructions(plan, index, verbose)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\instructions.py", line 148, in exec
ute_instructions
    cmd(state, arg)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\instructions.py", line 95, in UNLIN
K_CMD
    install.unlink(state['prefix'], arg)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\install.py", line 714, in unlink
    os.unlink(meta_path)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Anaconda2\\conda-meta\\conda-3.19
.1-py27_0.json'

[Anaconda2] C:\Users\User>
```

Try running the Anaconda prompt as admin:

[image]

Comment: Fetching package metadata: ......
Error: No packages found in current win-32 channels matching: cx_oracle