# DLL file load failed For Cx_oracle

Tags: python, path, cx-oracle, oracle-home

I'm using Python 3.1.2. I've downloaded cx_Oracle (Windows x86 Installer (Oracle 10g, Python 3.1)). I'm using Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64-bit.

I'm trying to access a remote Oracle server. I haven't installed any Oracle client. However, I use SQLTools 1.5.0, which I manually copy-pasted from some place.

I came to know cx_Oracle needs a DLL file from an Oracle client to access a remote database, so I copied all the DLL files from the folder of SQLTools to a location. I added the location where I kept the ora.dll into the system's environment variable (PATH and ORACLE_HOME). But it doesn't seem to work. I get the same error:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I'm missing something. Will this manual work do the job or do I have to install an Oracle client?

Comment: Why are you copying .DLL files around?  Why aren't you running the proper installers?

Comment: Because I don't have the rights to install in my computer. Will the proper installer do the job??

Comment: just having the same problem, seems you do need a local oracle client installation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711408/help-installing-cx-oracle

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle client isn't an installer, but a series of zip packages. Download the appropriate Instant Client from this [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html) (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html), unzip them, stick them on your C drive or anywhere you prefer, and add it to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH and ORACLE_HOME env vars.