# easy_install cx_Oracle (python package) on Windows

Tags: python, windows, easy-install, cx-oracle

So I found [Help installing cx_Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711408/help-installing-cx-oracle) but am still stuck.  I downloaded the latest instantclient from oracle, and set ORACLE_HOME to the location of the extracted files (both direct and with a bin folder between the ORACLE_HOME value and the files), but easy_install is popping an error when running setup.py saying it can't locate the Oracle include files.  I did notice that only the 11g dll is in the folder, do I need all 3 drivers present for setup to complete?  If so, where do I even get them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Honestly it is a hell of a lot easier to install cx_Oracle from one of the [binary installers](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/) they have, than from source.

## HOWTO for *nix:

1. Browse to [Instant Client for Linux x86 download page.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html)
2. Download the latest version of basic, sqlplus and sdk packages that fit your architecture (32 or 64bits):

   - `oracle-instantclient<version>-basic-<version_full>.<arch>.rpm`
   - `oracle-instantclient<version>-sqlplus-<version_full>.<arch>.rpm`
   - `oracle-instantclient<version>-devel-<version_full>.<arch>.rpm`.
3. Install the RPMs using alien. For example, at the time of this writing:

   ```
   $ sudo alien -i oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
   ```
4. Add necessary environment variables (I personally did put it in `/etc/environment` then logoff/back in to reload the env):

   ```
   ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/<version>/client64/lib/
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/<version>/client64/lib/
   ```
5. [Fix oracle's includes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24550818/1030960):

   ```
   $ sudo ln -s /usr/include/oracle/<version>/client $ORACLE_HOME/include  # for 32bits arch, OR
   $ sudo ln -s /usr/include/oracle/<version>/client64 $ORACLE_HOME/include  # for 64bits arch
   ```
6. Create `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient<version>-basic.conf`  and `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf` (for more recent versions, at least since 12.1) containing:

   ```
     /lib  
     /usr/lib/oracle/<version>/client/lib  ; for 32bits arch, OR
     /usr/lib/oracle/<version>/client64/lib  ; for 64bits arch
   ```
7. Reload ldconfig cache (use `-v` flag if you want some verbose):

   ```
   $ sudo ldconfig
   ```

You might need to install `libaio1`.

## HOWTO Install cx_Oracle

Assuming we have installed Oracle Instant Client 10, you have different alternatives to install [cx_Oracle](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/):

1. Install with [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip): `$ pip install cx_oracle` (linux only)
2. Download the installer/.tar.gz file from the [cx_oracle PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle) site

Older versions (version less than 5.1.2 are .msi and .rpm files) can be downloaded from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cx-oracle/files/).  Install the RPMs using alien. For example, at the time of this writing:
`$ sudo alien -i cx_Oracle-5.0-10g-py25-1.x86.rpm`

To test, `python -c 'import cx_Oracle; print cx_Oracle'` should return the modules with its version.

Comment: It seems like this should be as easy as getting MySQL working.  Freaking Oracle...

Comment: You haven't felt pain until you've tried to install cx_Oracle from source on a *nix machine. It's a pity it's such a PITA.

Comment: Oh joy, I can't wait.  That task is in my future.  Why does it not surprise me that this is the toolset from the same company that tried to de-opensource Java?

Comment: I'll dig up my old cx_Oracle install HOWTO for *nix and add it to the post when I find it if you like.

Comment: Added my HOWTO for *nix, should make your life easier.

Comment: I've updated this, but have not had a chance to test it.

Answer (score 10):

**step 1** check python is 32 bit or 64

```
import platform
platform.architecture()[0]#'32bit'
```

or
     [image]
**step 2** install oracle client (32 bit or 64 bit depends on python version from step1)

- download the oracle client from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win32soft-098987.html(link for32 bit version)
  download and extract the zip files in one folder
- the zip files are extracted to 'installation' in this case
- the directory will appear like this
  [image]

  - click on install and set the path to 'base' and 'software' directories

    - software directory should be inside base directory(recommended)
    - in this case 'installed' directory is base and 'software' directory is for software path
    - set ORACLE_HOME path:
    - set the oracle home path to the 'software' directory as 'F:\softwares\oracle11g32\installed\software'
    - in cmd check 'echo %ORACLE_HOME%' to see if the path is set properly

**step 3** install vcforpython27 or visual c++ 2008 express edition for python 2.7

- download it from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-sa/download/details.aspx?id=44266 (used this in this case to avoid installation of whole visual c++ 2008 as mentioned in below)
- it is a small package that contains c++ compilers for python 2.7
- (Or)
- visual c++ 2008 express edition ( https://www.microsoft.com/en-sa/download/details.aspx?id=5582 ) [it will around a 1 GB installation]
- vcforpython27 will installed at 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft'
- enable show hidden folder in windows to this these directories
  [image]
- set an environment variable with the name ' VS100COMNTOOLS'  with value as 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0'
- it should point to the point to the directory containing 'vcvarsall' batch file[image]
- echo %VS100COMNTOOL% to see if is pointing to the right directory in cmd
- And do the steps below:(from:[error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat) )
- go to C:/Python27/lib/distutils the file msvc9compiler.py. Find in it the function find_vcvarsall and do following modification.
  Replace the line:
  productdir = os.path.join(toolsdir, os.pardir, os.pardir, "VC")
  with
  productdir = os.path.join(toolsdir)
  This is where vcvarsall.bat resides in this case (check, where vcvarsall.bat is in your installation).

**install cx_Oracle**

```
 the easy step: pip install cx_oracle
```

if all the above steps are followed properly, then it should work. It took lot of pain to figure this out. I hope it will be useful.

**recommended to run:**

```
 pip install --upgrade setuptools
 from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667069/cannot-find-vcvarsall-bat-when-running-a-python-script
```

Comment: sorry but I need to have Oracle installed to get cx_Oracle to work? all I need is to make a little python function to test the connectivity to a database's instance.

Comment: Even I was wondering about the same question, but the libraries that the python needs to connect with Oracle database comes with complete installation. I could not find independent libraries or modules - like in postgres and mysql - to connect to Oracle database. If you did find such libraries or modules, please do share.

Comment: well it worked for me by just installing "Instant Client", here's a guide: http://mostperfect.net/blog/2010/07/28/installing-cx_oracle-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

1. Download oracle instant client (for 32bit or 64bit archtitect and appropriate version of Oracle (10g,11g,12g)).
   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html

Note: Requires an user to authenticate with an OTN (oracle tech network account).

1.1. Download and unzip "Instant Client Package - Basic" to 
C:\Python27\Scripts\instantclient_11_2
 e.g. 
  instantclient-basic-windows.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip

1.2. Download and unzip "Instant Client Package - SDK"  to C:\Python27\Scripts\instantclient_11_2
 e.g.
   instantclient-sdk-windows.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip

2. set ORACLE_HOME=C:\Python27\Scripts\instantclient_11_2
3. python -m pip install cx_Oracle

Output on success:
`Collecting cx_Oracle 
  Using cached cx_Oracle-5.2.1.tar.gz 
Building wheels for collected packages: cx-Oracle 
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cx-Oracle ... done 
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\m315468\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\7c\5f\96\ cd273c9b675bc7c28ae249b74d1f7df5d3eacba9e918715225 
Successfully built cx-Oracle 
Installing collected packages: cx-Oracle 
Successfully installed cx-Oracle-5.2.1`

Answer (score 0):

After struggling I found below method. I am using Windows and have separate environment for django.

1. Follow this [link](https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows) and go to Windows section. Now under Oracle
   "Instant Client Zip" you will see first step to download zip file
   depending on which version and bit you need. Download zip file.Remember django 2 dont support Oracle 11.
2. On Windows create below folder structure
   c:\oracle\instantclient_12_2
3. unzip your files under this folder.
4. Set the PATH in Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System Variables -> PATH. The Instant Client directory must come in PATH before any other Oracle directories.
5. Open other command prompt or restart current one.
6. conda activate
7. type python
8. run all below command one by one to test connection, mind the indentation at the last for loop.

   ```
   import cx_Oracle

   connection = cx_Oracle.connect("your_username", "your_psw", "localhost/orcl")

   cursor = connection.cursor()

   cursor.execute("""select to_char(sysdate, 'dd-mon-yyyy') from dual""")

   for cdate in cursor:

       print("Today the date is ", cdate)
   ```

Output:

```
 Today the date is  ('08-nov-2019',)
```