# Deploying cx_Oracle in Windows

Tags: python, windows, oracle11g, cx-oracle

I'm trying to use `cx_Oracle` module in python to access a remote database and insert or delete rows in tables. BTW I have downloaded oracle instant client 11.1 and also odbc and sqlplus versions. I have set environment variables `ORACLE_HOME` and `TNS_ADMIN` to directory I have unzipped files there and add this this directory to the `PATH` variable. As I googled I think there should be some `.ora` files but I can't find them.

I can use `sqlplus` commands from command line, but my main problem is that I can't install and use `cx_Oracle`. I don't want to use any command line scripts; I just want to use `cx_Oracle` as an API.

Can anyone give me a complete explanation, I'm really stuck there. All the documents in this area are vague. Best Regards.

**EDIT 1:**

I tried the source package of `cx_Oracle` with `python setup.py install` and `python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32` commands. I don't get the oracle error again, but I'm getting `command 'gcc' failed` error. I tried MinGW compiler and have edited environment variable `PATH` to contain MinGW install directory(e.g. `C:\MinGW`); I have also installed Microsoft Visual C++(versions 2005, 2008 and 2010); but I still get the error.

**EDIT 2:**

Since @jpmc26 mentioned about `tnsnames.ora` files, I decided to add that I have tried to make a `tnsnames.ora` and also a `sqlplus.ora` file and put them in directory `C:\oracle\instant_client_11_1\network\admin`; but as I googled I realized that if you use `cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, sid))` command, you can skip `.ora` files. `cx_Oracle.makedsn` would make the structure itself.

Comment: detailed answer is given here http://stackoverflow.com/a/35634151/5305401

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried a lot of ways to finally solve the problem. Since I think I should write a comprehensive answer, I will write the problems that I faced and their solutions respectively; hoping it can help others. I also changed the question's name to an appropriate one. Here's what I've been through during installation of `cx_Oracle` module in Windows 7 - 32 bit version(I think other versions of windows would have similar solutions, but I'm not sure):

- I have tried to install `cx_Oracle` using `easy_install` and I got
  the error `No oracle client installed`. I have downloaded oracle
  basic instant client and oracle sdk instant client for windows from
  Oracle Official Website and installed it via following steps:

  > Unzip oracle basic instant client into directory `C:\oracle\instant_client_11_1\`.
  >
  > Unzip oracle sdk instant client and copy folder `sdk` into the directory `C:\oracle\instant_client_11_1\`, consequently we have a directory as `C:\oracle\instant_client_11_1\sdk\`.
  >
  > Add `C:\oracle\instant_client_11_1\` to the end of the `PATH` environment variable.
  >
  > Add a new variable named `ORACLE_HOME` and set `C:\oracle\instant_client_11_1\` for the value.
  >
  > Restart computer.
- I tried to install `cx_Oracle` using `easy_install` again and I got
  error `command ‘gcc’ failed: no such file or directory` and in some
  cases `unable to find vcvarsall.bat`; this was because I didn’t have
  a C++ compiler, so I followed these steps to solve it:

  > Download Microsoft Visual C++ and install it.
  >
  > Download MinGW and install it; note that you must install GCC module.
  >
  > Add `C:\MinGW\` and `C:\MinGW\bin\`(which contains `gcc.exe`) to the end of the `PATH` environment variable.
- I tried to install `cx_Oracle` using `easy_install` again and I got
  error `command ‘gcc’ failed with exit status 1`; I tried this step to
  solve it:

  > Open file `C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\ cygwincompiler.py` and remove all `–mno-cygwin` occurrences in this file; this is because recent versions of `GCC` has removed `–mno-cygwin` option and it shouldn’t be there.
- I tried to install `cx_Oracle` using `easy_install` and it worked.

But during searching in the internet I found a couple of tricks that may be useful:

- If you got error `no module named win32api`, it’s because you didn’t
  install win32 extensions of python on your computer you should
  download `pywin32` module from [Source Forge](http://sourceforge.net)
  and install it.
- If you didn’t succeed anyway, you can try an older version of `cx_Oracle`; but keep in mind all we talked about in the above lines. You can find all versions of `cx_Oracle` [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cx-oracle/files/?source=directory).
- If you want to use `sqlplus` you should do some other steps too. For this purpose search the internet.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try some [pre-built binaries](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/). Unfortunately, the installer is an MSI, so installation using them with `virtualenv` would not be possible.

I believe what you're referring to with the `ora` file is the TNS names file. If so, it's a plain text file with a particular format. This might help: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora. According to the [FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/ic-faq-094177.html#A5028), Oracle will look in the `TNS_ADMIN` directory for the file `tnsnames.ora`. Note that using a TNS names file may be optional. In many cases, you can drop what you would normally put in the TNS names file (so something like `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORA11)))`) in the same place you would a TNS name.

Welcome to Oracle. Good luck. You'll need it. (Yes, everything is this complicated with Oracle.)

Comment: yes, I actually meant that and another file named sqlplus.ora(I have just heard it somewhere in [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)) and I've read the documents and build it; I'll add these details to the question. But as I googled, it is not required to have a `tnsnames.ora` file when you are using `cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, sid))`. `cx_Oracle` would make the structure itself. My current problem is about windows modules, if you can help about that.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi The prebuilt binaries don't help?

Comment: No. It didn't. But I solved the problem by removing all `–mno-cygwin` expressions from file `C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cygwincompiler.py`.  Since GCC has removed this option, its existence in this file makes an error.

Comment: Actually I will find the link and post an answer ASAP. Thanks a lot for paying attention.