# Error while importing cx_Oracle on windows

Tags: python-2.7, cx-oracle

I am facing a problem while installing cx_Oracle module.

I have installed Oracle Sql developer using which I can connect to any Oracle Server. I have also installed cx_oracle module. Now when I try to import the module I am reciving below mentioned error.

> > > import cx_Oracle
> > >
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > >           import cx_Oracle
> > >
> > > ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

After googling I can find that they want me to install Oracle client, but since I already have Oracle Sql developer which can act as a oracle client, I am unable to find the difference between two. Can someone please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You will need C-language based Oracle "client" libraries installed on your local machine. (SQL Developer uses Java libraries). To connect to a remote database you can install the Oracle Instant Client.

Answer (score 0):

I have explained installation steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472060/deploying-cx-oracle-in-windows?answertab=active#tab-top) for 32 bit OS and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23467014/command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1-while-installing-cx-oracle-on-windows-64?answertab=active#tab-top) for 64 bit OS.

BTW, you have to add your `oracle_instant_client` path to your `PATH` environment variable. The error you've got is because the OS did not load required DLL files for `oracle`.