# cx_Oracle: distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate Oracle include files

Tags: linux, oracle, python-2.5, cx-oracle

I need install cx_Oracle for Python 2.5 on Linux (Linux 2.6.18-371.1.2.el5 i686). I have installed Oracle client 10.2.0.4.

I have tried following:
1. Download `cx_Oracle tar.gz` from `http://sourceforge.net/projects/cx-oracle/files/`. 
I don't know which of listed version are suitable for python 2.5 and Oracle client 10.2.0.4, so try cx_Oracle-5.1.tar.gz. Unpacked tar, 
go to unpacked folder and run python setup.py install. I got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 187, in <module>
raise DistutilsSetupError("cannot locate Oracle include files")
distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate Oracle include files
```

In .bash_profile I have setted oracle path:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/oracle/10.2.0.4/client
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
```

How fix such error, maybe I need another version of cx_Oracle tar?

1. Run  pip install cx_Oracle. Got error:

Downloading/unpacking cx-Oracle

```
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement cx-Oracle
No distributions at all found for cx-Oracle
```

Could someone advise me right solution?

**Update**
After suggestion in response I got following error:

```
...
cx_Oracle.c:496: warning: passing argument 3 of âPyModule_AddIntConstantâ makes integer from  pointer without a cast
cx_Oracle.c:497: error: âOCI_UCBTYPE_EXITâ undeclared (first use in this function)
cx_Oracle.c:497: warning: passing argument 3 of âPyModule_AddIntConstantâ makes integer from pointer without a cast
cx_Oracle.c:498: error: âOCI_UCBTYPE_REPLACEâ undeclared (first use in this function)
cx_Oracle.c:498: warning: passing argument 3 of âPyModule_AddIntConstantâ makes integer from pointer without a cast
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 14):

When you run setup.py it will check for any of these folders on your ORACLE_HOME.

```
possibleIncludeDirs = ["rdbms/demo", "rdbms/public", "network/public",
        "sdk/include"]
```

Also the instant client sometimes places the include files, such as oci.h, in /usr/include/oracle//client, if there is no 'include' directory under ORACLE_HOME create a symbolic link to it.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/include/oracle/11.2/client $ORACLE_HOME/include
```

Looks like you're missing the [Client SDK](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/oci/instantclient/index.html)

Comment: I tried create symbolic link, it doesn't help, but I try just add empty folder include in /usr/oracle/10.2.0.4/client/network. This fixed error, but I got new, please see in updated question for details

Comment: @khris Try downloading the sdk and extracting on your client, it should create the sdk/include folder. I added the link to the answer.

Comment: Could you pleas give direct link becase in Client SDK page I see a lot of stuff, like Content Management SDK and don't know what exactly I need to download. Thanks

Comment: I cannot directly link to the file, go to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxsoft-082809.html  and search for  'Instant Client Package - SDK: Additional header files and an example makefile for developing Oracle applications with Instant Client' for your oracle version.

Comment: Thank you! The following commands helped me: `sudo mkdir $ORACLE_HOME/sdk/` `sudo ln -s /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client $ORACLE_HOME/sdk/include`

Comment: I have the SDK and I still get the same error. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435990/cx-oracle-distutils-errors-distutilssetuperror-cannot-locate-oracle-include-fi

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you install the instant client sdk for you OS.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Install `oracle_client_basic`

   ```
   oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm
   ```
2. Using pip install

   ```
   python -m pip install cx_Oracle
   ```
3. Adding ldconfig

   1. Find your client location, for example: `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib`
   2. `vi /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf`

      Add this location into it:

      ```
      /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib
      ```
   3. `ldconfig`
4. `import cx_oracle`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've a client sdk present in your path.

Also I had to do add this to my .bash_rc

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
```

In addition to this, Python 2.7 does not come with Python.h which is available by default in Python 3.4. So I would also suggest to install python-devel package

```
yum install python-devel
```

That should resolve the issue.