# ImportError when importing cx_Oracle python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-oracle

ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. I have researched for 2 days but unable to resolve. Need help!!

Answer (score 0):

there's a lot of different reasons you might get this error, but your question really doesn't have enough information. You mention cx_Oracle in the title, but are you sure you have it installed correctly? The cx_Oracle website, for example, mentions:

> `pip install cx_Oracle` (**on platforms other than Windows**) or download
>   directly from PyPI.

This answer might help: [easy_install cx_Oracle (python package) on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245985/easy-install-cx-oracle-python-package-on-windows#11246173)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Python, cx_Oracle and Oracle Client are all 64-bit or all 32-bit. If one of them is different you can get this error.

Comment: My python 2.7 is 64 bit (AMD 64) but I'm not sure if i install the right cx_Oracle how to check that?

Comment: Make sure you downloaded and installed the version with amd64 in the name from PyPI (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle/5.2.1). If you're on Windows, though, it should complain if you are installing the wrong version. If you just copied it in, though, you could make that happen. Also, make sure you are using the 64-bit version of Oracle Instant Client.