# How to install cx_Oracle on Windows with existing Oracle client?

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I want to access a workplace Oracle database with user authentification in Python (Anaconda installation) via cx_Oracle on Windows.

I was following the instructions from [easy_install cx_Oracle (python package) on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245985/easy-install-cx-oracle-python-package-on-windows) and have downloaded both Oracle Instant Client and Microsoft Visual Studio.

However, the Oracle Instant Client does not allow me to access the database because I believe it does not have the permissions. Is there a way I can download cx_Oracle by using the Oracle client used at my workplace?

Also, excuse my newbie question, but does having access to an Oracle database mean I have Oracle installed?

Thanks!

Comment: What error are you receiving when you say it doesn't allow you to access the database?

Comment: I am currently accessing the Oracle Databases through Toad for Data Analysts and when I use the Instant Client option no databases are available in the drop-down menu, so there's no explicit error message.

Comment: Having access to Oracle doesn't mean you have Oracle database installed I presume this is what most people term Oracle installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can install cx_Oracle 6 which provides a binary wheel (precompiled package) that handles all 11.2, 12.1 and 12.2 Oracle clients using the following command:

```
python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade --pre
```