# Suggestion for loading data of 2M records in to DB

Tags: oracle, java-8, clob, sql-loader

Users upload data file through application (JSF) which has 2 million records, i have to upload it to DB. Loading through JAVA asynchronous call is occupying more memory out-of memory exception and also most of the time it is getting timeout.
So for that what i did is, stored uploaded file as CLOB in table1, i use UNIX shell script which runs every 15 minutes to see if table1 has not-processed records, if then read that CLOB file and load in to table2 using SQLLDR in the same shell script.It is working fine, but there is a 15 minutes delay in processing records.
So i think the same SQLLDR process can be run through a PL/SQL package or procedure and the same package can be called through JAVA JDBC call.. rite? any examples?

Answer (score 0):

If it's one-time export/import you can use SQL Developer. It enables you to export displayed rows in a loader format. B/Clobs are exported as separate files.

Following [Oracle's blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/searchtech/loading-documents-and-other-file-data-into-the-oracle-database):

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'loader.txt'
  INTO TABLE my_table
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  ( id         CHAR(10),
    author     CHAR(30),
    created    DATE "YYYY-MM-DD" ":created",
    fname      FILLER CHAR(80),
    text       LOBFILE(fname) TERMINATED BY EOF
  )
```

> "fname" is an arbitrary label, we could have used "fred" and it would
>   have worked exactly the same. It just needs to be the same on the two
>   lines where it is used.

```
loader.txt:
1,John Smith,2015-04-29,file1.txt
2,Pete Jones,2013-01-31,file2.txt
```

If you want to know how to dump a CLOB column into a file, please refer to [Dumping CLOB fields into files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311084/dumping-clob-fields-into-files).

Comment: @Krzyztof no it is not one-time. I am planning to use shell scripting

Comment: from the client or server? if server, why not data pump?