# How to write a CLOB to an OS file in Oracle without using UTL_FILE package?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, clob

I have a variable `xml_` which is a CLOB data type variable I use to store some XML data using a PL/SQL procedure dynamically.
I need to write this CLOB data into a file in my machine. The database server is not my machine.
Is there any way to do this?
I am using Oracle 11g.

I am using the procedure given as an answer in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311084/dumping-clob-fields-into-files), but it uses UTL_FILE package , and as I don't have direct access to the database server machine, I would like to know how to write the file into a directory in my local machine instead.

Edit:
I am creating the xml dynamically. I tried to store the data in a table with a CLOB column, but it shows `<value error>` when I try to see the data using PLSQL Developer. I am thinking it is because the size of the xml is too large to open from the PLSQL editor or there is something wrong with the created data. Hence I am trying to write the data to a file to check if there are some invalid characters etc.

Edit2:
I got this resolved via Oracle SQL Developer.
The CLOB data was over 2 GB, Oracle SQL Developer showed me the column data, hence I was able to export it into a file in my client machine itself.

Comment: If you want to write to the client file system, you'd need a program running on the client (i.e. not PL/SQL).  `SQL*Plus` via the `spool` command can write to a file on the client.  You can save a CLOB to a file from SQL Developer.  Pretty much any other IDE should be able to do the same thing.

Comment: I am creating the xml dynamically. I tried to store the data in a table with a CLOB column, but it shows <value error> when I try to see the data using PLSQL Developer.
I am thinking it is because the size of the xml is too large to open from the PLSQL editor or there is something wrong with the created data. 
Hence I am trying to write the data to a file  to check if there are some invalid characters etc. 
Can you please tell me how I can use SQL plus to write my variable data/column data to a file? 
I am a newbie to Oracle.

Comment: @UthpalaDl The PL/SQL Developer `<value error>` sometimes only happens in specific tabs of the Large Data Editor. Try clicking on the Text tab.

Comment: @JonHeller Hey Jon, I finally was able to see the CLOB column data using Oracle SQL Developer. I tried another few options as well like using SQL Plus tool which also worked, even though it took a long time to write the data. :) Thank you for your input!