# Unable to spool the clob column which is having the line size > 32676 in oracle

Tags: oracle

i have tried spooling and also using the dbms_lob. still not able to  export the clob columns which is having lenght of 45000

below is the code :

spool file header

set head off
set verify off
set echo off
set pages 0
set long 20000
set longc 20000
set lines 32767
set trimspool on
set feedback off
set termout off

--- util script

```
SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
  l_file utl_file.file_type;
  l_clob CLOB;
  l_buffer VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_amount binary_integer := 32767;
  l_pos INTEGER           := 1;
BEGIN
  SELECT mo_xml
  INTO l_clob
  FROM
    ( SELECT mo_xml, LENGTH(mo_xml) LEN FROM test_xml ORDER BY LEN ASC
    )
  WHERE rownum =1;
  l_file      := utl_file.fopen('test', 'TEMP.TXT', 'w', 32767);
  LOOP
    dbms_lob.read (l_clob, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);
    utl_file.put(l_file, l_buffer);
    utl_file.fflush(l_file);
    l_pos := l_pos + l_amount;
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
WHEN no_data_found THEN
  -- Expected end.
  IF utl_file.is_open(l_file) THEN
    utl_file.fclose(l_file);
  END IF;
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  IF utl_file.is_open(l_file) THEN
    utl_file.fclose(l_file);
  END IF;
  raise;
END;
/
```

Comment: Why [`SET LONG 20000`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG087)? *Sets maximum width (in bytes)*

Comment: i tried to change the value but the issue is in the set line, cant able to print the values which is having length > 32767

Comment: Ah, you are about writing into the file at some server directory? This has nothing with `spool` command of SQL*Plus so all the options at the beginning are not relevant at all (why have you included them?). So check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25640512/2778710)

Comment: i have added that here to mention that , i have tried both ways, spooling through sql plus and through util script , but nothing worked

Answer (score 1):

Try using [DBMS_LOB.CLOB2FILE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_LOB.html#GUID-006129FC-1335-4B9F-9D9A-40130F6D6F45) instead.

```
declare
    v_clob clob;
begin
    select mo_xml
    into v_clob
    from (select mo_xml from test_xml order by dbms_lob.getlength(mo_xml))
    where rownum = 1;

    --In 12.2 and above:
    dbms_lob.clob2file(v_clob, flocation => 'test', fname => 'TEMP.TXT');
    --In 11.2 and below the procedure is in a different package:
    --dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file(v_clob, flocation => 'TEMP_DIR', fname => 'TEST.TXT');
end;
/
```

Comment: I tired dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file yesterday, it will process only one row. In our table we have 2k records.  We can go with the dbms_lob.clob2file / dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file if we have only one record. 

Thanks for your time on this. :-)

Comment: @Balakrishnan Do you want each of the 2K records to be in a separate file? Or are you trying to concatenate all of the records into a single file?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say that, but even the official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#ARPLS70940) for utl_file.put says "The maximum size of the buffer parameter (it is the second one, where your "l_buffer" goes) is 32767 bytes". I believe you have to split lines first and flush them one by one to a file afterwards

Comment: i cannot split the lines because i am framing an xml which should be transferred to third party

Comment: @Balakrishnan Do you want to put all the XMLs from multiple rows into a single file or as different documents? Or as some nested structures inside big XML?