# Oracle table data export to my local machine

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have 2000+ records in my table .table has clob data .
I want to save all records as single files on my local machine.
I am using pl/sql developer and Oracle 11g database.

Comment: So you want 2000+ files each containing a record? I'm almost afraid to ask why.

Comment: Do you just want to export the clob column? I can't speak for PL/SQL Developer, but Toad has an option to export blob/clob/etc columns into individual files. Maybe PL/SQL Devloper has something similar? Or if not, maybe Oracle's SQL Developer has something?

Comment: mmmmmpie :business need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do this if you have access to the file system on your database.
You can find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434443/exporting-a-clob-to-a-text-file-using-sqldeveloper).

Comment: the same i achieved with SPOOL