# Oracle SQL - Export to single-line file a very long text

Tags: sql, json, oracle, export, clob

I have a serious problem exporting the data from Oracle SQL to a text file. The problem is that I have a one table with single row and single column with type CLOB. The text length in this cell is almost a 2 billion characters JSON string.

What I need to do it is to export this (and longer texts in the future) to a single-line JSON file. But... the problem is that when I'm exporting it using a Oracle SQL Developer - the text is cut after 4000'th character. If I'm trying to export it using sqlplus - it's even worse (80 chars max).

I use Oracle 12.2 SQL.

Any help will be highly appreciated!!
Thank you in advance and best regards,
Tom

Comment: see here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434443/exporting-a-clob-to-a-text-file-using-oracle-sql-developer

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately - I work for a bank and the security here is pretty tight, so there's no way I can access a server's hard-drive. That's why I'm looking for a solution on the client side. The other solution mentioned in referenced topic is either not working (selecting whole result set and exporting) nor can be achieved (whole export will take up to 20GB of JSON string so Excel simply can't handle it).

I'm wondering if there's an option to cut the string into 4000 chars pieces and append it piece-by-piece into a file....?